# Clarification: Any simple way to update the layouts to viewbinding in onCreate?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to know if there any easy migration for the app from layouts to viewbinding enabled in android studio.

Comment: What do you mean by "easy migration"? What are you calling easy here. Please be more specific.

Comment: Inside the code can I migrate this with out editing manually declaring the binding and other stuffs like need to replace the Id to the binding.id

Answer (score 1):

Enable ViewBinding in your Gradle file:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: This is okay, But inside the code can I migrate this with out editing manually?

Comment: never heard that actually